# Computing a corrective regression forecasting factor

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, forecasting

I am working on forecasting problem using a regression model like gradient boosting to predict the number of weekly sold shoes.

I am using the historical data only from last year to predict the sales in current year.

Now, I am comparing my forecasted results with real observations of current number of shoes sold in current year.

I can see that there are some gap (not always consistent) between my forecast & what really happened (orange and blue graphs). This could be because of many features that probably I do not have control (like some events, changes in marketing strategy, etc..)

I am wondering how I can compute a corrective factor to apply on my forecast to come in future weeks (dotted blue graph-Future forecast on Graph) to kind of scale or boost my future forecast.

I cannot do another regression between my recent observation and their coresponding forecasts, since I do not have many observations in current year.

So, based on current graph, any recommendation how to compute a factor to reduce gap of forecast and future observation after week 10 ?

[image]

Thanks